# Opacity transition css animation works from higher to lower but not vice versa

Tags: javascript, css

I have what should be a very simple problem, perhaps a typo that I just can't see.I have a page blocker that grays the page out with an opacity transition and blocks any clicks when I launch a form. This works in hideForm, but does not in showForm and it immediately become 0.4 opacity. Weird because all they are doing is the opposite of each other with a timeout in hideForm to set's it to display to none when opacity transition is finished.

I think this will end being a simple solution and I'll end up being asked to delete the question, which I will gladly do, but I've been trying to solve this for too long and I need a second pair of eyes.

I tried to minimize the amount of code shown but will post more if asked.

```
#pageCover {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    display:none
}
```

This works great

```
    function hideForm() {
        if (form.style.top > '0px') {
            pageCover.style.opacity = 0.0;
            setTimeout(function () { pageCover.style.display = 'none'; }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

This displays the pageCover but ignores the transition and goes right to 0.4 . How can the transition work one way, but not the opposite way? I'm stumped.

```
    function showForm() {
        if (form.style.top < '0px') {
            pageCover.style.opacity = 0.4;
            pageCover.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: ^^ not a jsfiddle, a runnable **on-site** example using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: replace the second line in the `showForm` function with `setTimeout(function () { pageCover.style.display = 'block'; }, 1000);`. Anyway, I'm waiting for an executable demo.

Comment: I tried that. All it did was delay pageCover from displaying, but it did not execute the transition and still goes immediately to 0.4

Comment: I don't currently have a jsfiddle account nor any hosting and I'm just learning using local host. Do I need that for this problem and this amount of code? Don't know what seeing the execution will do as it behaves exactly how I described

Comment: @Bobh - You don't need an account to create anonymous fiddles, But again, don't use jsFiddle, use the built-in Stack Snippets here on-site. See [the link I gave you above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). Providing a runnable example helps ensure that your question is complete and correct (for instance, you would have caught the fact you have too many `}` in both of your functions), and makes it easier for people to provide answers for you. That's in your best interest.

Comment: You saw an extra { because for brevity, I left out the if statement which I didn't include for brevity's sake and should have. Code edited above and is exact code I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opacity attribute animates but not the "display" attribute. When they are set at the same time, the opacity transition will not be observed. You can play with the numbers but for illustration's sake, let's add a 10ms gap between the two operations:

```
pageCover.style.display = 'block';
setTimeout(function(){
  pageCover.style.opacity = 0.4;
},10);
```

You can push the number to even 0, but the browser might "optimize" it away.

Live Example:

```js
const pageCover = document.getElementById("pageCover");

function hideForm() {
    pageCover.style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function () {
      pageCover.style.display = 'none';
    }, 1000);
}

function showForm() {
    pageCover.style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(function () {
      pageCover.style.opacity = 0.4;
    }, 10);
}

document.getElementById("btn-show").addEventListener("click", showForm);
document.getElementById("btn-hide").addEventListener("click", hideForm);
```

```css
#pageCover {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageCover">
  This is the page cover
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn-show" value="Show">
<input type="button" id="btn-hide" value="Hide">
```

Comment: The snippet does not work reliably, which is making my head hurt.

Comment: @Pointy - Ah, the joys of rendering vagaries. I see what you mean, for me about one in six times it just appears without the fade-in (on Chrome, it's more often on Firefox). If I up the delay to 50ms, it seems to be reliable (on Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: That's a very obscure fact, but given those are the rules, it makes sense and it works. Thank you. I doubt I would have found something that obscure.